# CGAL Extrusion implementation

Tags: 3d, mesh, cgal

I'm trying to extrude a flat 2D polygon using cgal. I know there is no method to automatically do this using CGAL, so I would like some help on how to do it. 
To provide you with some details, I've meshed the input 2D polygon and created two polyhedral parallel faces by modifying the 'z' coordinate, to have each vertex as:

v(x,y,0)
and
v_parallel(x,y,height)

The problem is when trying to mesh the sides. Triangles are usually not consistently oriented and it would require to re-orient the whole set again. 
My questions are:

1. Is this a correct way to implement an extrusion using CGAL?
2. If so, do I have to build the side face triangles by my self? Or there is a built-in CGAL method to automatically connect the boundaries of these two parallel faces?